# creating a git diff to include all source files in repo

Tags: git, diff

Let me give the context first before explaining the requirement. We want to post a review on the reviewboard server with all source files in the repo. the reason is that we want to do some security related review on all the files and want to record the comments before fixing the issues. Reviewboard can upload the diffs. So if I can create a review with all source files being shown in diff format, this might work with reviewboard.

Can anybody tell me a good way to generate this kind of diff? Alternatively, can anyone suggest a good method to achieve the end goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a commit (on a branch) that deletes every file in the repository. That would create a diff with negative lines for every existing line. It wouldn't be that hard:

```
$ cd my_repo
$ git checkout -b delete_everything
$ git rm -r .
$ git commit -m "Remove every file"
```

You could similarly then revert that commit, creating another commit with positive lines for every existing line.

```
$ git revert -n HEAD
$ git commit -m "Re-add every file"
```

Either of these could work for loading into Review Board.

Comment: The second commit works well for loading in the reviewboard. Reviewboard for some reason did not display the diff for the first commit. But anyways, thanks a lot - it was fairly simple solution- i was thinking more in terms of git diff providing such a functionality.